# Next Auth email credential without default signIn page

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Is there a solution to use credential email - password from backend
without the default authentication page provided from Next/auth?

I must use Modal instead of full-page authentication

I follow the doc:"https://next-auth.js.org/providers/credentials" but when I use the SignIn from nextAuth it generates a signIn Page

[image]

Comment: Currently I don't think it supports it out of the box. I followed this thread and was able to implement it though: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/791

Comment: how about next iron session mate ? is that suitable for this usecase ?

Answer (score 4):

Add your own [custom login page](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages) if any and/or a [sign-in button](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#signin) that uses a function that is provided by NextAuth. See below how it is done.

#### Custom Login Page

In your *api/auth/[...nextauth].js* file add this option.

```js
export default NextAuth({
  ...
   pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
});
```

#### NextAuth Sign In Function

```js
 signIn('credentials', {
   redirect: false,
   callbackUrl: '/',
   username: ...,
   password: ...,
 })
```